# Spark: Transform array to Column with size of Array using Map iterable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following data

```scala
df.show

+---------+--------------------+------------+
|     name| age|         tokens| tokensCount|
+---------+----+---------------+------------+
|    Alice|  29|        [A,B,C]|           3|
|      Bob|  28|      [A,B,C,D]|           4|
|  Charlie|  29|    [A,B,C,D,E]|           5|    
+---------+----+---------------+------------+
```

I transform data with following command

```scala
val newDF = df.select(($"name") +: (0 until 4).map(i => ($"tokens")(i).alias(s"token$i")): _*).show

+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     name| token0| token1| token2| token3| 
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    Alice|      A|      B|      C|   null|
|      Bob|      A|      B|      C|      D|
|  Charlie|      A|      B|      C|      D|
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**I want to give `tokensCount` instead of static value `4` at `(0 until 4)`**

I tried a few things like `$"tokensCount"` and `size($"tokens")`, but could not get through.

Can anyone suggest how to loop or map according to the size of array or count of array ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code to find the maximum length of `tokens`, and then use that to create the necessary columns:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Alice", 29, Array("A", "B", "C")),
  ("Bob", 28, Array("A", "B", "C", "D")),
  ("Charlie", 29, Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")),
).toDF("name", "age", "tokens")

val maxTokenCount = df.withColumn("token_count", size(col("tokens"))).agg(max("token_count") as "mtc")

val newDF = df.select(($"name") +: (0 until maxTokenCount.first.getInt(0)).map(i => ($"tokens")(i).alias(s"token$i")): _*).show
```

Which will give you:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   name|token0|token1|token2|token3|token4|
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  Alice|     A|     B|     C|  null|  null|
|    Bob|     A|     B|     C|     D|  null|
|Charlie|     A|     B|     C|     D|     E|
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

It might be useful to explain why you want to do this transformation, as there might be a much more efficient way. This has the potential to create a very sparse dataframe. Imagine that most names have no tokens, but Bob has 100 tokens: all of a sudden you have one hundred columns of mostly null values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment is genuine. One issue resolved that gave birth to new one :)  I have `mtc = 147` and there are several tuples, where i have `null`, which is not a desired transformation for the input where this DataFrame have to go. I will think on it and write a comment to explain a bit more tomorrow. If possible, give a remark/comment. Many thanks

Comment: Infact, i want to build a binary table for a given set of tokens(e g., A, B,C,D,E). For a specific name, if there exists a token, it should get 1, else 0. For that i have made a schema with nested StructType object.